# cygstart --directory switch is ignored when using --action=runas

Tags: windows-7, cygwin, uac

It seems the `--directory` switch is ineffective when used with `--action=runas` when using `cygstart`. For example:

```
cygstart --action=runas --directory=`cygpath -wa $PWD` cmd.exe /k dir
```

The expected output is the contents of the working directory of the cygwin shell the command was run from. Instead, it outputs the contents of `C:\Windows\system32`, the default starting path for an administrative command prompt, completely ignoring the `--directory` switch. In contrast, omitting the `--action=runas` switch gives the expected output, but obviously not with elevated permissions.

The following is an effective workaround:

```
cygstart --action=runas cmd.exe /k "cd /d $(cygpath -wa $PWD) & dir"
```

It works, but it would be nice if the `--directory` switch worked as intended. Does anyone have any insight on this? Is it a bug with `cygstart`, or with how UAC/Windows works?

Comment: It happens to me too. Seems to be a bug. CygWin is still buggy in many aspects (progresssing fast, but buggy), the command-line installer, for example, like in the section `Is there a command-line installer?` here: http://www.cygwin.com/install.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, it's not a bug - it's [expected behavior](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2014-10/msg00059.html). The cygwin maintainers themselves expect you to do exactly what you did in the workaround.

To me, it certainly feels like a bug, though. After all, this is one of the cases that I hardly care *how* things are done, as long as they do what they promised. And `--directory` just doesn't work in this scenario, without any kind of warning or whatever. (I don't really have the heart to defend this point of view on the mailing list.)

So yeah, unfortunately, there is no other way than `cd`ing into the target folder.

Comment: Interesting. Can't say I agree either, but I use Cygwin too infrequently to argue it either. Thanks for the insight.